# Using a URL to display a movie

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using a custom camera overlay to capture a video. I am trying to display the video the user took in another view, but it is not working. I am using this code to get the URL

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

self.movieURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSLog(@"Createing testing");

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}
```

And this to display it

```
self.movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[self.movieController setContentURL:self.movieURL];

[self.movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 320, 568)];

[self.view addSubview:self.movieController.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.movieController];

[self.movieController play];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get video url with this

```
self.movieURL =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>> Url %@", [self.movieURL absoluteString]);
```

Comment: and make sure you have used delegate "UIImagePickerControllerDelegate" in .h file